# Determinar si una matriz es simétrica

Tags: java, array, matemáticas

Tengo una matriz 3x3, la cual debo recorrer y, de acuerdo a unos parámetros establecidos retornar un String, uno de los ejemplos es el siguiente:

```
matriz = {(1,0,1),
          (0,1,0),
          (1,0,1)}
```

a esta matriz la paso por esta condición.

```
if(matriz[0][0]==1 && matriz[1][1] == 1 && matriz[2][2]==1 ){
                 System.out.println("\nLa matriz es reflexiva");
            }
```

A lo cual debe retornarme el string `"La matriz es reflexiva"` ya que se cuentan los 1 de la diagonal que empieza en la posición `[0][0]`, hasta la posición `[2][2]`.

Requiero de ayuda para crear una condición que me revise las posiciones `[0,1]` con `[1,0]`, `[0,2]` con `[2,0]` y `[1,2]` con `[2,1]`;

Si las tres parejas o al menos una tiene un 1 guardado retorne el String `"La matriz es simetrica"`.

Nota: Si al menos una de las parejas tiene números diferentes `(1,0 o 0,1)`, se tendrá que salir del ciclo sin retornar nada a cambio.

Answer (score 4):

> A una matriz cuadrada MxM, se la llama **simétrica** cuando se cumple que el valor en la fila *`i`*, columna *`j`*, es igual al valor en la fila *`j`*, columna *`i`*, para todo par `(i,j)`.
>
> ---
>
> > [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, lo que se debe hacer es recorrer la matriz, sabiendo que no será simétrica sii
`matriz[i][j] != matriz[j][i]`.

```
public static boolean esSimetrica( int matriz[][] )
{
    for ( int fila=1; fila < matriz.length; fila++ )
    {
        for ( int columna=0; columna < fila; columna++ )
        {
            if ( matriz[fila][columna] != matriz[columna][fila] )
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Como verás,

- el bucle más interno no recorre todos los valores de `columna`, sólo los menores a `fila`, porque los que sean mayores van a ser comparados después.
- el bucle externo no empieza en 0, sino en 1, porque, por el punto anterior, sólo los comparamos con índices menores.

Para tu caso, lo llamarías así:

```
if(esSimetrica(matriz))
{
    System.out.println("La matriz es simétrica.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estarías buscando algo así , es un ciñe a lo que estabas preguntando:

```
    if(matriz[0][1]!=matriz[1][0] || matriz[0][2]!=matriz[2][0] || matriz[2][1]!=matriz[2][1] ){
        //Dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer:      
        //break -> Para el programa y finaliza su ejecución;
        //return -> No devuelve nada, y el programa continua; 
    }else{
        if((matriz[0][1]==1 && matriz[1][0]==1) ||(matriz[0][2]==1 && matriz[2][0]==1)  || (matriz[1][2]==1 && matriz[2][1]==1)  ){
        System.out.println("\nLa matriz es simetrica");
        }
    }
```

Espero que te ayude.